# How to push object into a object AngularJS 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am trying to do use the angular push function but it is not working.

I want to  objects into an Object.

I searched for basic examples here at Stack Overflow but I couldn't find it.

Can anyone correct my code or write a very basic example?

Here is my example.

For instance, from these two objects :

```
var object1 = {
    "color": "yellow",
    "size" : null,
    "age" : 7,
    "weight" : null
}

var object2 = {
    "color": "blue",
    "size" : 51,
    "age" : null
}
```

I want  Object Global :

```
var Global=
{
    "color": "yellow",
    "size" : null,
    "age" : 7,
    "weight" : null
},
{
    "color": "blue",
    "size" : 51,
    "age" : null
};
```

Comment: Your `Global` will be an **array** of objects, so initialise it with `var Global = [];` and append your objects with `Global.push(object1)`, etc. (even shorter: `Global = [object1, object2];`

Comment: Thinks for your reponse but I need Global a Object not array

Comment: then you need a name for each object: `Global = {"object1":object1, "objetc2":object2}`, or if you want to initialise it first: `Global = {};`, `Global["object1"] = object1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to declare your variable as an array:

```
var Global = [];
```

and then you can push your Objects in the array:

```
Global.push(object1);
Global.push(object2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [];

const object1 = {
    "color": "yellow",
    "size" : null,
    "age" : 7,
    "weight" : null
}
const object2 = {
    "color": "blue",
    "size" : 51,
    "age" : null
}

data.push(object1, object2);

let Global = {};
Global = {...data};

console.log(Global);
```

Answer (score 0):

Push is a function of the prototype Array, not available for plain Object.